# Sublime Text - Python environment, when breakpointing

Tags: python, debugging, sublimetext3, pdb

Is there a way to configure in Sublime Text to have this neat feature (that exists on PyCharm for instance) that allows you to have a python interpreter console whenever you have a breakpoint in your code with the current context of the variables ? (I know you can get a PDB console, but I'm referring to a fully-blown python console interpreter)

Best.

Answer (score 0):

It has some [debuggers](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Debugger), but they look very old and hacky.

Only free, fully fleged comparison to PyCharm is currently [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com). It has really nice debugger, you can read and see more [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging).